# Is it possible to call RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly with target-architecture?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com-interop

I have a problem when calling when calling the RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly() method. I am writing an installer program, which should be as general as possible. This installer program calls RegisterAssembly and is built with "Any CPU" build target.

The installer program is supposed to register components specified by the user in a config file. This could for example be a DLL. My problem occurs when trying to register a DLL built with target x86. The call to RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly() fails, in the case when the installer program (built with "Any CPU") is run on a x64 platform, since the RegisterAssembly call tries to register a x64 binary but in fact is a 32 bit.

So in short, somehow I would like to call say to the RegisterAssembly method that it should try to register a 32-bit assembly when the assembly is 32 bit and otherwise register a 64 bit assembly. Is there any way to do that other than having to rebuild the installer program for both platforms?